# WooCommerce Order Completed List Style

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to modify the "Completed Order Page" in WooCommerce:

[Photo Of Current Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xHAP.png)

And i'm currently attempting to make the email value:

- The last element of the list
- Wider, so it doesn't break the email in
  two lines

I have tried adding the following code:

```
.woocommerce-order-overview .woocommerce-thankyou-order-details .order_details

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul li:first-child {
  order: 1;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) {
  order: 5;
  max-width: 66.66%;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) {
  order: 3;
}

ul li:nth-child(5) {
  order: 4;
}
```

And although it solves the problem and gives me the desired output, it also modifies all the ul and li elements of **the entire website**. I'm sure it is a declaration problem, but I've tried different classes and can't seem to find how to make it work.

This is the structure of the HTML:

```
                </div>        <div class="page-content entry-content">
            <div class="woocommerce">
<div class="woocommerce-order">

    
        
            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received">Thank you, your order has been completed.</p>

            <ul class="woocommerce-order-overview woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__order order">
                    Order Id:                   <strong>0000</strong>
                </li>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__date date">
                    Date:                   <strong>19/08/2020</strong>
                </li>

                                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__email email">
                        Email:                      <strong>exampleofanemail@outlook.com</strong>
                    </li>
                
                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
                    Total:                  <strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>979</bdi></span></strong>
                </li>

                                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method method">
                        Payment Method:                     <strong>PayPal</strong>
                    </li>
                
            </ul>
```

Could someone please help me with this one?

Note: I can only add css to the "Customize" section of WooCommerce, as I can't access the child's HTML or CSS files.

Comment: please add html code instead of showing it's screensot

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`white-space: nowrap;` makes the text in single line

```
ul li:nth-child(3) {
   white-space: nowrap;
   order: 5;
}
```

OR

```
ul li.email {
   white-space: nowrap;
   order: 5;
}
```

For more info :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

Comment: Thank you, this can replace the part where I display the 66.66%.

Although, it will continue to modify all the elements of the website, and not only the needed section.

I'm looking more for an answer that targets the specific class that i need to declare on the css so it only modify the specific elements of this ul.

Comment: can you useul `ul li.email` instead of  `ul li:nth-child(3)`.?. please try this. :)

Comment: Nice! It helped me a lot! I also added: 

order: 5; to the css in order to display it in the last position. Thank you so much! :)